# Ubuntu , windows and dos in a laptop

Tags: system-installation

I have purchased a lenovo thinkpad  laptop with dos os in it. I want to install windows 7 and ubuntu in it. I purchased windows 7 and installed to 1 drvie (100gb) and i have 1gb dos partition. I added 2 more partition while windows installation (one for data and other for ubuntu). While ubuntu installation it did not detect windows 7. It detects dos only. After ubuntu installation in boot menu there is no windows 7....

So i inserted windows cd --> recovery option --> cmd terminal -->
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rbuildbcd

I tried this now i am able to boot windows ... Now ubuntu is missing

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If windows have NTFS partition and ubuntu have ext3,4 than window will not show the ubuntu in your laptop/PC , so you can Dowload Easybcd software it is free for home user install it open it you will see add new entry click on it and select "GRUB2" and swap partition (when you install ubuntu it take some swap partition other wise use default c:\ partition) go to linux tab add entry click on edit boot menu select the appropriate timeout option and save setting.

for more use watch youtube videos of easyBCD.

After that restart the pc and you can see 2 options, windows and ubuntu/linux.